# ImportError: No module named options.value_provider

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

Following pipeline works with DirectRunner but raises exception below with DataflowRunner. 
How do I go about debugging such errors? This appears to be pretty opaque to me.

```
p = beam.Pipeline("DataflowRunner", argv=[
    '--project', project,
    '--staging_location', staging_location,
    '--temp_location', temp_location,
    '--output', output_gcs
])  
(p  
 | 'read events' >> beam.io.Read(beam.io.BigQuerySource(query=query, use_standard_sql=True))
 | 'write' >> beam.io.WriteToText(output_gcs)
)   
p.run().wait_until_finish()
```

raises

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dataflow_worker/batchworker.py", line 578, in do_work
    work_executor.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dataflow_worker/executor.py", line 165, in execute
    op.start()
  File "dataflow_worker/operations.py", line 350, in dataflow_worker.operations.DoOperation.start (dataflow_worker/operations.c:13064)
    def start(self):
  File "dataflow_worker/operations.py", line 351, in dataflow_worker.operations.DoOperation.start (dataflow_worker/operations.c:12958)
    with self.scoped_start_state:
  File "dataflow_worker/operations.py", line 356, in dataflow_worker.operations.DoOperation.start (dataflow_worker/operations.c:12159)
    pickler.loads(self.spec.serialized_fn))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apache_beam/internal/pickler.py", line 212, in loads
    return dill.loads(s)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dill/dill.py", line 277, in loads
    return load(file)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dill/dill.py", line 266, in load
    obj = pik.load()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 858, in load
    dispatch[key](self)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 1090, in load_global
    klass = self.find_class(module, name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dill/dill.py", line 423, in find_class
    return StockUnpickler.find_class(self, module, name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 1124, in find_class
    __import__(module)
ImportError: No module named options.value_provider
```

Comment: What sdk version are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

value_provider is a module introduced recently for handling templates in the python SDK. However, I don't see any template in your snippet, so it is probably a package mismatch. Are you using matching versions for the SDK and the worker? You can check your worker-startup logs to check the versions of packages you have installed.

Comment: You are right. Issue turned out to be SDK mismatch. Locally I had both apache_beam and google-cloud-dataflow "pip installed". Uninstalling apache_beam cleaned up this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Same issue here. As pointed by Maria, it's a mismatch problem between apache_beam and google-cloud-dataflow packages.

Just to make it clear, the following command solves it:

```
pip2 install --upgrade apache_beam google-cloud-dataflow
```